# jQuery delegate method not working for keydown and keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want that when TAB key is pressed to execute my code and `e.preventDefault();`. For testing I have checked the below events with only `alert(9);`:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("div").delegate(".note","keydown",function(e){
        //not working
    });

    $("div").delegate(".note","keypress",function(e){
        //not working
    });

    $("div").delegate(".note","click",function(e){
        //working fine
    });
});
```

Only click event works while keypress and keydown doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/5BpEQ/

Comment: same here -> http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/Uuc5g/

Comment: As a sidenote, `$().ready` is not recommended, you should use `$(document).ready`, not that it would solve the problem or anything!

Comment: Is note a form? If not, then how do you expect to capture a keydown event on anything except a form?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `keydown` and `keypress` have the target of `body` unless an element is in focus:

> When an element is focused, key events received by the document must
>   be targeted **at that element**. There may be no element focused; when no
>   element is focused, key events received by the document must be
>   targeted **at the body element**.

source: https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/editing.html#focus

So the problem is not delegating itself but rather making an element focusable (your handlers just don't fire!). For an arbitrary element to be able to recieve focus, use the `tabindex` attribute for the elements that are supposed to have key event handlers (learn more [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute)).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work if ".note" in an element that accepts focus.

**JS**

```
$(function(){
   $("div").delegate(".note","keydown",function(e){
       if(e.originalEvent.keyCode == 9){
           console.log('Tada!');
           e.preventDefault();
       }
    });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/fcEx5/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this implementation, it is a little bit more complex than what you asked but you can leverage it, it uses `on()` instead of `delegate()` which is recommended :

```
<button id="myButton"> Click Me </button>
<input type="text" id="myText" />
```

the js

```
function myFunction(){
     alert("hi!");
}



$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#myButton").on("click",myFunction);
    $("#myText").on("keydown",function(e){
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
        if (keyCode == 9) { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            myFunction();
          } 
    });

});
```

The TAB button or a click on the button will trigger the function, also some documentation about `on()`

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

And finally here is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/gRC9W/)

Comment: FYI jQuery Event objects already have `e.which` normalized which is preferred.