# Form not submitting on ENTER when no type="submit" element present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

We're using custom buttons to submit forms. A click event is assigned to .btn-submit's to submit the respective form. However, without some type of `<button type="submit">` or `<input type="submit">` element located within the `<form>`, pressing ENTER in either the username or password text field does not submit the form.

How do I still allow users to submit a form when pressing ENTER in an `input` field without a `type="submit"` element present in the `<form>`?

HTML

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
<p><b>Username</b> <input type="text" name="username" style="width: 300px; font-size: 18px"></p>
<p><b>Password</b> <input type="password" name="password" style="width: 300px; font-size: 18px"></p>

<input type="hidden" name="user_login" value="1">
<div class="btn-inline btn-green btn-submit">Log In</div>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.btn-submit').on('click', function(e)
    {
        $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to capture the enter key press, preferably using jQuery delegates on the form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button)

Comment: why you're not don't want to add a button (type=submit)? you can make it invisible via css: `display: none`

Comment: See parody' answer.  It's close to what you want and what I'd snippet for you.   Instead of doing a button click element after the preventDefault, just form.submit()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do something like this to make it so when the enter key is pressed within the input it activates the submit button

```
$('form').keypress(function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if( code === 13 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $( ".btn-submit" ).click();
    };
});
```

**EDIT**

This wont cause the submit button to be clicked if return is pressed in the `textarea` it will only do that for `input`s of the type `text` now.

```
$('input:text').keypress(function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if( code === 13 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $( ".btn-submit" ).click();
    };
});
```

Comment: How might I be able to prevent the Enter keypress event when users a typing in a `<textarea>`?

Comment: i just added a edit that will only do it for text inputs in the form now

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the enter key press, preferably using jQuery delegates on the form.   Just target your delegate at the form and looking at input elements, or body looking at form, I suppose. Essentially it's saying "look at this top element, trigger X action on the inner element".   Your parent would be form, inner input, action is keydown or keyup

See this :
[jQuery delegate method not working for keydown and keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117910/jquery-delegate-method-not-working-for-keydown-and-keypress)

Then in the function test for what keypress was hit.   If enter, submit.  If not, return false.

PS:  when I'm not on mobile, I can do a code snippet for you.

Answer (score 0):

And here is why:

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form. It can only be attached to `<form>` elements. Forms can
>   be submitted either by clicking an explicit `<input type="submit">`,
>   `<input type="image">`, or `<button type="submit">`, or by pressing Enter
>   when certain form elements have focus.
>
> Depending on the browser, the Enter key may only cause a form
>   submission if the form has exactly one text field, or only when there
>   is a submit button present. The interface should not rely on a
>   particular behavior for this key unless the issue is forced by
>   observing the keypress event for presses of the Enter key.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/submit/